# Remover aspas duplas no codeigniter query builder

Tags: php, codeigniter, postgresql, oracle

Estou usando o framework Codeigniter e toda vez que crio um select com query builder deles, ele coloca aspas duplas em todas colunas e tabelas.

Ex: SELECT "ID", "NOME" FROM "ALUNO"

Isso acaba me dando problema, pois uso 2 conexões com banco de dados, oracle e pgsql. No oracle funciona normalmente, já no pgsql me retorna erro.

Sei que se eu colocar o ultimo parametro nas minhas funções como false, ele funciona, porém queria saber se tem algum parametro global pra fazer isso, ou vou ter que ficar passando método por método o false ?

Comment: qual versão do CI você está utilizando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use esta linha antes da sua consulta (documentação [aqui](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#protecting-identifiers)):

```php
$this->db->_protect_identifiers = false;
```

Para um parâmetro global, no arquivo `./application/config/database.php` (arquivo de configuração do banco de dados), adicione um novo elemento ao `array` de configurações padrão:

```php
$db['default']['_protect_identifiers'] = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

O CodeIgniter tem um segundo parâmetro no query builder para evitar o escape de palavras, veja [este link](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=query%20builder#CI_DB_query_builder::select) com a documentação, mas em suma você pode usar algo assim:

```
$this->db->select('campo', false)
```

Comment: Ou seja, vou ter que ficar colocando false em todos os parametros, não tem algum lugar que posso já deixar sem como padrão ?

Comment: Infelizmente sim, não creio que haja uma configuração global, porque teoricamente isso é uma má prática de código, permite o SQL Injection muito facilmente. Você pode tentar alterar direto dentro do framework na classe do Query Builder, mas não aconselho